# What is the difference between 财政 and 金融？

Tags: word

Both phrases are synonym in my opinion and can be interchangeable, until one day I realized I might be mistaken when I saw in an official document of a city, that there are two government agencies listed side by side in the same page, one being 财政局, the other 金融办.

So what is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

财 = 财務 (finance)

政 = 政策 (policy)

- 财政 = finance(n); financial(adj) - *personal, institutional, or governmental*
- 金融 = financial(adj). It is short for 金融市場 (financial market) - *melting of metal represented currency issuance and circulation, which in turn represented the market economy*

Example:

我的财政由我太太管理 -- My finances are managed by my wife

美國的财政由财政部長掌管 -- U.S. finances are run by the Secretary of the Treasury

金融機構 = financial institution (for example: banks)

财政部 = governmental financial (policy) department

金融監管局 = financial market supervisory authority

> one being 财政局, the other 金融办. So what is the difference?

财政局 control the government's finances (e.g. national budget); 金融办 supervises the financial market (e.g. stock trading)

Answer (score 0):

财政 and 金融 both concern "finance", but the former is more positioned in regards such as "manage the money/balance the book" at the government level. The latter regards more in the "financial activities(burrowing/landing)/money flow" in the commercial market.

财政局 is the "bureau of finance"; 金融办 could be an office/group branched out/under the 财政局.

Comment: Can you translate 金融办 into English to enable me to see its difference with 财政局?  @PdotWang below has told us the different name in the US, but as China prefers to use finance to mean both, it is very confusing.

Comment: 金融辦，即地方政府金融服務(工作)辦公室的簡稱。金融辦一般作為地方政府(county/city)下轄的一個辦公室，一般與地方政府各部門同級別. The equivalent in English should be "the office of financial services", or "the department of finance". 财政局是省級的金融單位,再上去是財政部(國家級), they all handle finance matters but at different levels and focus.

Answer (score 0):

中国财政部 = Ministry of Finance of the People's Republic of China

United States Department of the Treasury = 美国财政部

金融机构 = financial institution (Banks)

Basically, 财政 deals with revenue and balance (income and spending). 金融 deals with money and investment.

Answer (score 0):

In PRC,

1. 中央财经委员会 Central Financial and Economic Affairs Commission

makes economic and financial policies (including fiscal policies).

2. 财政部 Ministry of Finance

carries out fiscal policies according to the instructions from CFEAC at a national level.

3. (地方)财政局 (Local) Bureau of Finance

carries out fiscal policies at a local (provincial, municipal, county) level.

4. 金融办 Finance Office = 金融监督管理局 Bureau of Local Financial Regulation and Supervision

regulates financial activities at a local (provincial, municipal, county) level.

财政部 is a *de facto* branch of 中央财经委员会.

地方财政局 and 金融办 are branches of the local government.

A 地方财政局 has close ties with 财政部, a 金融办 is not.

Answer (score 0):

"财政" and "金融" both refer to the scope of economics.

The differences are the "财政" laying more emphasis on the administration's fiscal duty to enact and implement the policies for tax revenue, budget, expenditure, which belongs to macroeconomics.The combined word "财政"  can be divided into single words "财" and "政" separately.

"财" means wealth, here can be apprehended to industrial, agricultural as well as service productions,  in addition to tax revenue.

"政" means government administration, which refers to fiscal policies.

Correspondent of "财政", the "金融" is more likely we talked financial daily. Similarly, the combined word "金融" can be detached into "金" and "融".

"金" literally means gold, the money.

"融" means circulation, including debit and lend, through circulating from lend to debit, fortunes appreciate.
It analogizes to the share, fund market nowadays. I think these belong to non-official activities, namely microeconomics.